# Why does Angular 8 required validation behave differently with ngValue?

Tags: angular

I have a select defined as

```
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="gasDistributionUtilityId">
          <option [ngValue]="null">
            -- Select a name --
          </option>
          <option *ngFor="let lookup of gasDistributionUtilities"
                  [ngValue]="lookup.value">
            {{lookup.label}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

One of the values in gasDistributionUtilities is 0 to indicate None. If I bind the option with `[value]="lookup.value"` the None entry fails required validation because the value used for the check is null. Binding with `[ngValue]="lookup.value"` works as expected. All of the values are numbers, why is 0 treated differently? Or should I not mix `[value]` and `[ngValue]` for the options?

Comment: @ConnorsFan With `[value]` it's "0: null", "0", "162", etc. With `[ngValue]` it's "0: null", "1: 0", "2: 162", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option persistence in memory

When an `<option>` has its value assigned by `[ngValue]="value"`, the value is stored in a property

`_optionMap: Map<string, any>`

where the key is the option's index. So if you have this select:

```
<select>
  <option [value]="10"></option>
  <option [ngValue]="20"></option>
  <option [value]="30"></option>
  <option [ngValue]="40"></option>
</select>
```

You would have an `_optionMap` of:

```
[ "1", 20 ],
[ "3", 40 ]
```

#### Option persistence in HTML

These options are persisted in the HTML value as `value="{index}: {value}"`.

The options set via `[value]` are persisted in the HTML as plain string values.

#### Finding the selected option

When retrieving the value, the HTML value is split by `:`, and the bit before the colon is used as a key to retrieve possible values from the `_optionMap`.

So if you have the following HTML:

```html
<option [ngValue]="null"></option>
<option [value]="0"></option>
```

The `_optionMap` will look like this:

```
["0", null]
```

And the `0` value will be treated as the key `"0"`, for which the value `null` will be found in the map.

#### Conclusion

It's safer to pick one of `[ngValue]` or `[value]` to work with in any given `<select>`. Especially if you have numeric keys.

The [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption) are ambiguous at best when it comes to stating the circumstances under which inputs should be used.

> @Input() ngValue: any Tracks the value bound to the option element. Unlike the value binding, ngValue supports binding to objects.
>
> @Input() value: any Tracks simple string values bound to the option element. For objects, use the ngValue input binding.

They imply that you can mix and match inputs within the same `<select>` without thinking about it. If you have `[value]="someNumber"`, you're potentially going to have problems when combined with `[ngValue]`.

The example below will never select the values `0` or `2`, because they collide with `[ngValue]` indexes:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()">
  <option [ngValue]="10">10</option>
  <option [value]="0">0</option>
  <option [ngValue]="20">20</option>
  <option [value]="2">2</option>
</select>
```

#### DEMO

I figured this out by creating a playground with a forked version of `ngValue`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzx7cj

`ngValue` source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts

Comment: I think there's another nuance here in that it appears that ngValue uses reference equality and value uses truthiness (I guess). That explains how I got to the point of mixing them, because [value]="null" didn't work.

Comment: I would have thought so. The input value itself is stored as the value in the option map. There wouldn't be any reason to do that unless you wanted to compare references if it's an object. The comparison is done by some injected comparer, which I'm sure someone with more of an appetite for this could find in the source code. I'm content with going along with your assumption :)