# Angular formGroup : select default value

Tags: angular

In Angular, I want to select the default value in the select boxes.

```
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
....
....
export class CastComponent implements OnInit {
public form: FormGroup;
public contactList: FormArray;
get contactFormGroup() {
  return this.form.get('contacts') as FormArray;
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    crew_name: [null],
    crew_role: [null],
    contacts: this.fb.array([this.createContact()]),
  });
  this.contactList = this.form.get('contacts') as FormArray;
}
...
...
}
```

In the `.html` file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
<p class="mb-3">&nbsp;</p>
<h3>Crew</h3>
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label class="required">Member Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
        <label class="required">Role</label>
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Director"> -->
        <select class="form-control" type="text" >
          <option [ngValue]="">Select</option>
          <option [ngValue]="1">Director</option>
          <option [ngValue]="2">Music Composer</option>
          <option [ngValue]="3">Writer</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<span formArrayName="contacts">
  <div class="row mb-4" *ngFor="let contact of contactFormGroup.controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="crew_name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Writer"> -->
        <select class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="crew_role">
          <option [ngValue]="">Select</option>
          <option [ngValue]="1">Director</option>
          <option [ngValue]="2">Music Composer</option>
          <option [ngValue]="3">Writer</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"><p class="add-more mb-3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="removeContact(i)"> - remove</a></p></div>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
<p class="add-more mb-3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="addContact()">+ add</a></p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save & Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

How can I select the default value in the select boxes as above?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element

Comment: please set crew_role as '' in this.form = this.fb.group({
    crew_role: [''] });

Comment: When you bind an HTML form control to the form you have created, it will take on the value from the `FormControl`. You're setting `null` in the `crew_role` `FormControl` rather than an actual value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `crew_role` `<select>` isn't defaulting to the `Select` value because you're not setting the correct value when building the form.

In your HTML you have

```html
<select class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="crew_role">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Director</option>
  <option value="2">Music Composer</option>
  <option value="3">Writer</option>
</select>
```

The `Select` option has the value `""`. You are setting it to `null` when you build the form.

Instead of

```
crew_role: [null],
```

You should have

```
crew_role: this.fb.control(''),
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozgh6g

Comment: Thanks! I have just did some amendments in the question. instead value="1" , I did [ngValue]="1" [ngValue]="2" etc. Can you modify your answer based on this?

Comment: Why would you use `ngValue` instead of `value` when you just have simple keys?

Comment: No prob :) Just so you know, `ngValue` and `value` must be treated with a bit of care. I did an in-depth answer on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60626545/5367916

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="crew_role">
          <option [value]="null">Select</option>
          <option [value]="1">Director</option>
          <option [value]="2">Music Composer</option>
          <option [value]="3">Writer</option>
        </select>

this.form = this.fb.group({
    crew_name: [null],
    crew_role: [null],
    contacts: this.fb.array([this.createContact()]),
  });
```

just use [value]="null"